# How do one systematically self-learn math?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

If one wants to self-study advanced undergraduate courses or basic graduate courses, how to promise that the knowledge is "systematically" organized? I don't even know how to define "systematical" there, will it be like "unifying advanced ideas"?

Comment: Let's omit the buzzwords "advanced" and "basic". You start with set theory and propositional logic. Work your way to calculus and eventually analysis and topology. In parallel work on linear algebra. That is my vision of what an undergraduate should have some understanding of. There are other subjects as well, but it is not so much about a specific subject, rather the techniques you acquire while tackling the material.

Comment: The only way I can think of to make sure you get the right education is to actually follow the curriculums of some university. If you're just beginning you'd want to learn linear algebra, set theory, calculus, then abstract algebra, multivariate calculus, complex analysis, measure theory, functional analysis, probability, and so on. Follow the topics that are usually learned, that way you'll know you're doing it right. You should solve many exercises because it's not possible to learn math passively. You can use online lectures or learn from books that are considered good (can be hard).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! My background is actually that I'm not a pure math major but very interested in topics such as dynamics, number theory, but when I really began to do researches, my teacher found me not working systematically enough. However, I'm not very sure that this word means what I think it does. Now I think maybe I need to change the aim of my training. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To address what I think is your notion of "systematical" or "unifying", most math courses are "separate" from each other. For example, you do not need to know real analysis to do a course in abstract algebra. You do not need to know number theory to do a course in graph theory, etc. Of course, there is some overlap and interplay with subjects, but for the most part you can learn them separately. It is not like the lower level math courses, which do build upon each other (for the lower level courses, one does calculus I, then calculus II, then calculus III, and differential equations).

Comment: On the same time I think Linear Algebra shouldn't be learned 'separately'. That is, once you finish learning the basics, it's important to immediately use it. In my university we got slapped with some operations research, this is where we were forced to be fluent dealing with matrices. And then, one still needs to realize that linear algebra is not a study about matrices, not at all. When you start needing a lot of linear algebra is when you will start appreciating all of those seemingly 'random' concepts like change of basis, the usage of various decompositions, isomorphism theorems.

Comment: But (though I am not the best student) for linear algebra I think it's perfectly fine not understanding why you would want to know SVD or spectral decomposition the first time around. When you actually need it and look back at it, you would appreciate it a lot! I think understanding vector spaces, basis, kernels, homo/iso-morphisms, and first isomorphism theorem is enough to get you through the other subjects (I did). Then understanding colspace vs rowspace is also pretty important, but you shouldn't force it (it will come naturally, pressure is the best teacher of linear algebra).